# Why these tracking sites are informed when visitors come to my web?

Tags: web, tracking, disconnect

Some months ago I have published a website made with Django to AWS. Some weeks ago I installed DISCONNECT plugin to my Firefox browser and now I see there are several tracking sites that are informed when visitors come to my place. Why is this happening?

I don't like this, I'm not tracking my visitors, I don't want to do it and I don't want tracking sites being informed when my readers come to my place. This is the partial list of the tracking sites:

- doubleclick.net
- viglink.com
- bluekai.com
- exelator.com
- pippio.com
- rezync.com
- narrative.io
- v12group.com
- etc.

Some of them store cookies and use the local storage.

I wish to avoid or block these sites so my users are not tracked. How can I do it? Are they related to the robots that index my site?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably read the ToS for AWS.  I'm sure it says somewhere in there that they can track your users.  Maybe there is a hosting tier you can pay extra for that won't track them.

Comment: Thanks, Justin, I don't think its AWS who is tracking my users, their ToS say: Customers maintain ownership of their customer content and select which AWS services process, store and host their customer content. We do not access or use customer content for any purpose without the customer’s consent. We never use customer content or derive information from it for marketing or advertising.